# [android ndk]How can I get absoulte path of files in asset folder?

Tags: android, c++, path, android-ndk, assets

I'm using ftgles library on android native app.

but i can't rendering a text.

this is my source code.

```
unsigned char* buff;
unsigned long size;

buff = GLManager::getInstance()->texture()->loadFontFromAssets("NanumGothic.ttf", &size);

font = new FTBufferFont(buff, size);
```

I think this code is wrong.

so I'm trying to

change this code

```
font = new FTBufferFont(buff, size);
```

to

```
font = new FTBufferFont("filePath");
```

but I don't know the absolute path of assets folder's file

could you teach me how to get assets folder's file absolute path?

Comment: The assets folder is inside the apk archive (it's not extracted).  That is why you need to use the API to access it.  Note the apk is just a zip file, so you can use other methods to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Assets are not files, and you cannot use fopen() for them, which FTBufferFont(const char*) does under the hood. But you can extract an asset to a regular file if you wish, especially if you need this for debugging your code.